# "Continuation" in info column of SIP Traffic using wireshark

Tags: sip, wireshark

When capturing wireless traffic for Mobile VoIP applications using `wireshark`, we are seeing continuation messages in SIP protocol. Here network elements are using TCP element for SIP protocol. Hence, we are unable to see any VoIP call streams under Telephony. We are even able to capture RTP stream completely.

Is there any alternative solution to overcome this issue and to capture normal VoIP streams under the Telephony tab. Have attached the screen shot of the Log for the same.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Kindly help me out to proceed ahead to measure the quality of VoIP call.

Comment: You indicate you attached a screen shot, but no such attachment exists in this question.

Comment: I am Not able to see expected SIP traffic flow, right now iam able to see only SIP registeration packet and following SIP packets display as Continuation in info tab. you can find the "Continuation" SIP packet screen shot above. Kindly let me know wat the issue is and how to proceed further.